# Heard (his saying/him saying/him say)

Tags: grammar, possessives, objects, possessive-adjectives

When telling somebody what you did in order to get (to discover, to see) what somebody else did, what should I say?

For example:
Let me hear you say "i got it!"

So I do something in order to get (in this case, i hear) what somebody else does (says the "I got it" phrase).

Variants:

```
 1. Let me hear your saying "I got it!"
 2. Let me hear you saying "I got it!"
 3. Let me hear you say "I got it"
 4. (Maybe even your own?)
```

Somewhere in the internet I saw somebody claiming that the correct is "his doing", like it's his action being the property.

However, I heard in the "Hateful eight" movie the black guy saying "Let me hear you say i got it!".

I like the second variant of this construction, which is, for example, "I heard the black guy saying..."

So which of them all should I use, and if it's not the only one variant available, what are the rules for this kind of a construction?

By the way, if you can change the title, question and tags in such a way that English teachers will understand it better, I would really appreciate that, because I don't know how exactly to express this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are asking of the listener

> Let me hear your saying "I got it!"

means the listener has a *saying* named "I got it!", like a poem

> Let me hear your poem.

the possessive means the poem *belongs* to the listener.

Whereas

> Let me hear you saying "I got it!"

Can be slightly incomplete, but means you want the listener to be saying *something* while they might also be *doing something*

> Let me hear you whistling *while you work*.

Whereas

> Let me hear you say "I got it"

means you want the listener to say "I got it!"

Whereas

> Let me hear, you're saying "I got it!"?

means I want the hear what you are saying, are you saying "I got it!"?